# Load more data from database button PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

```html
   <section class="comments-section" id="comments">
  
      <h2 class="h2 center">Partagez vos temoignages </h2>
      <p class="paragraph center">Laissez la haine et le mépris à l'extérieur ! Ici on écrit que des choses positives.</p>
    <div class="container">
      <form method="POST" id="comment_form">
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="comment_name" id="comment_name" class="form-control" placeholder="Nom ou pseudo" />
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <textarea style="resize: none;" name="comment_content" id="comment_content" class="form-control" placeholder="Redigez votre commentaire" maxlength="700" rows="10"></textarea>
       </div>
       <div class="form-group">
        <input type="hidden" name="comment_id" id="comment_id" value="0" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Publier" />
       </div>
      </form>
      <span id="comment_message"></span>
      <br />
    

      <div class="all-comments" id="all">
  
            <div class="content" id="display_comment"></div>
            
        
      </div>


</section>
```

I have comment system on my website and I would like to add Load More button to hide comments and show only the first three and to load the rest of comments when clicked on button. These comments are from my DB. I have tried a lot of exemples but I'm still stucking...

Have you any solution please? Thanks

```
<?php

//fetch_comment.php

$connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', 'root', '');

// select from DB

$query = "
SELECT * FROM comments 
WHERE parent_comment_id = '0' 
ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT 3
";

$statement = $connect->prepare($query);

$statement->execute();

$result = $statement->fetchAll();
$output = '';
foreach($result as $row)
{
 $output .= '
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">Par <b>'.$row["comment_sender_name"].'</b> le <i>'.$row["date"].'</i></div>
  <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>
  <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><button type="button" style="font-size:1rem;"class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'">Répondre</button></div>
 </div>
 
 ';

 
 $output .= get_reply_comment($connect, $row["comment_id"]);
}

echo $output;

function get_reply_comment($connect, $parent_id = 0, $marginleft = 0)
{
 $query = "
 SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent_comment_id = '".$parent_id."'
 ";
 $output = '';
 $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
 $statement->execute();
 $result = $statement->fetchAll();
 $count = $statement->rowCount();
 if($parent_id == 0)
 {
  $marginleft = 0;
 }
 else
 {
  $marginleft = $marginleft + 48;
 }
 if($count > 0)
 {
  foreach($result as $row)
  {
   $output .= '
   <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left:'.$marginleft.'px">
    <div class="panel-heading">By <b>'.$row["comment_sender_name"].'</b> le <i>'.$row["date"].'</i></div>
    <div class="panel-body">'.$row["comment"].'</div>
    <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><button type="button" style="font-size:1rem;" class="btn btn-default reply" id="'.$row["comment_id"].'">Répondre</button></div>
   </div>
   ';
   $output .= get_reply_comment($connect, $row["comment_id"], $marginleft);
  }
 }
 return $output;
}

?>
```

Comment: your question is unclear but about your solution you should handle it as front side , at page load you send `3` as parameter for get result and rest of the requests you send to backend should has just page for pagination stuff

Comment: I don't know how many comments there can be, it depends on the visitor, I always want the first three to be displayed

Comment: user can specify number of comments?

Comment: No, but I don't know how many people will comment, if there are 100 or 1000 comments, I would like the first three to always be visible and to show the rest when button clicked or the next 3 comments

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment the `limit`

you need to have two variables, start record number, and the number of records to show, and then send them to the prepared statement. here is some inspiration:

```php
  <?php

    //fetch_comment.php

    $connect = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing', 'root', '');

    // select from DB

    $num_records_to_fetch = 3;
    $index_to_fetch_from = 0;

    // TODO: input filtering, validating int
    if(isset($_GET['chunk'])){
        $index_to_fetch_from = $_GET['chunk'];
    }

    $query = "
    SELECT * FROM comments 
    WHERE parent_comment_id = '0' 
    ORDER BY comment_id DESC LIMIT :start :numrecs 
    ";

    $statement = $connect->prepare($query);

    $statement->execute(array(':start' => $index_to_fetch_from, ':numrecs' => $num_records_to_fetch));

    $result = $statement->fetchAll();
    $output = '';
    foreach ($result as $row) {
        $output .= '
     <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">Par <b>' . $row["comment_sender_name"] . '</b> le <i>' . $row["date"] . '</i></div>
      <div class="panel-body">' . $row["comment"] . '</div>
      <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><button type="button" style="font-size:1rem;"class="btn btn-default reply" id="' . $row["comment_id"] . '">Répondre</button></div>
     </div>
     
     ';


        $output .= get_reply_comment($connect, $row["comment_id"]);
    }

    echo $output;

    function get_reply_comment($connect, $parent_id = 0, $marginleft = 0)
    {
        $query = "
     SELECT * FROM comments WHERE parent_comment_id = '" . $parent_id . "'
     ";
        $output = '';
        $statement = $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement->execute();
        $result = $statement->fetchAll();
        $count = $statement->rowCount();
        if ($parent_id == 0) {
            $marginleft = 0;
        } else {
            $marginleft = $marginleft + 48;
        }
        if ($count > 0) {
            foreach ($result as $row) {
                $output .= '
       <div class="panel panel-default" style="margin-left:' . $marginleft . 'px">
        <div class="panel-heading">By <b>' . $row["comment_sender_name"] . '</b> le <i>' . $row["date"] . '</i></div>
        <div class="panel-body">' . $row["comment"] . '</div>
        <div class="panel-footer" align="right"><button type="button" style="font-size:1rem;" class="btn btn-default reply" id="' . $row["comment_id"] . '">Répondre</button></div>
       </div>
       ';
                $output .= get_reply_comment($connect, $row["comment_id"], $marginleft);
            }
        }
        return $output;
    }

    ?>
```